# Why do setting up URISource for BitmapImage object requires a Begin and End init?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I was trying to set the source property of the wpf image class through code behind and for reasons unknown it was not working.

This is how my code looked like

```
 1 BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
 2 img.UriSource = new Uri("C:\\data\\pictures\dkn.jpg");
 3 pict.Source = img;
```

and then i did a bit of googling and i found that i need to change my code like below.

```
 1 BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
 2 img.BeginInit();
 3 img.UriSource = new Uri("C:\\data\\pictures\dkn.jpg");
 4 img.EndInit(); 
 5 pict.Source = img;
```

But what i could not understand is line 2 and 4 above.What is the significance of a begin and end init before and after setting up the urisource property.I was expecting the urisource property to behave as a normal clr property would.

Any thoughts please.

Comment: See the *Remarks* section in [ISupportInitialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.isupportinitialize.aspx). You could alternatively use the BitmapImage [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms602473) with an Uri argument and write `pict.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("C:\\data\\pictures\dkn.jpg"));`

Comment: And also the *Remarks* section in [BitmapImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms619218) of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Begin and End init Specifies that the object supports a simple, transacted notification for batch initialization of properties - MSDN